# when the epoll_wait(edge triggered) receive EPOLLIN event

Tags: linux, epoll

The fd in epoll will set to non-blocking，and regist with EPOLLIN event. if i don't  read until EAGAIN each time,and the epoll_wait can receive the read event？I find a mail ([golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/gxwCl0fsVqc)) with a description like this:

> One of the harder considerations about using edge-triggered epoll is you have to read()/write() until EGAIN, otherwise you will not receive another read/write event for the socket when you call epoll_wait.

I write a demo [epollserver.cpp](https://www.onlinegdb.com/Hy9q3h30B),
 the server listens on port 12439 and reads only 1 character at a time,like:

```
while(1)
    {
        int num = epoll_wait(epfd, events, BUFSIZE, -1);
        char buf[BUFSIZE] = {0};
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN){
                std::cout << "Ready to read!\n";
                int size;
                std::cout << "size=" << (size = read(events[i].data.fd, buf, 1) ,buf[size] = 0,size)
                          << "\t buf=[" << buf << ']' << std::endl;
            }
        }

    }
```

The client use `nc -4 localhost 12439` and sends 4 characters at a time

However,the server `epoll_wait` can receive read event every time.

So，i wonder if i misanderstand something?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `epoll_wait()` will wake you up repeatedly until you have read all the input.  This is the default behavior, unless you use the `EPOLLET` flag to enable edge-triggered mode.

Comment: If the client sends 4 characters each time, but server reads only one.In this case，whether the server calls  `epoll_wait` can receive another read event? @Eloff

Comment: @G.yang: Yes, correct, the server will be woken up continuously until it has consumed all available data.  The quote you posted in your question from golang-nuts is about "edge triggered" epoll which is only relevant if you use EPOLLET which you are not using (and you do not want to use).

Comment: oh,sorry! my demo is "edge triggered",not "level triggered".That what i was wondering

Comment: Oh well when I wrote this answer I don't think you had posted or mentioned anything about using EPOLLET.  If you are using EPOLLET then you must remember which descriptors are ready until you get EAGAIN on them.  Just because your application works now doesn't mean the code is correct--probably you're just getting "lucky" somehow.